# change mvc ajax pager html format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination

I have a mvc ajax pager control like below

```
@Ajax.Pager(Model.pagedListPageControlModel, null, null, new PagerOptions
{
    PageIndexParameterName = "pager",
    ShowDisabledPagerItems = false,  
    SeparatorHtml = "&nbsp;",
    CurrentPagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<a class=\"selected\" href=\"#\">{0}</a>"
}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "targetPanel"}, new { @class = "pager"})
```

That renders html like:

```
<div class="pager">
<a href='#'>1</a>
<div>
```

I need to change to:

```
<div class="pager">
<ul>
<li>    
<a href='#'>1</a></li></ul>
    <div>
```

format. Can anyone know how to do it ?